# Running travis tests on remote server, synching with github

Tags: unit-testing, github, deployment, build, travis-ci

I'm working on a package which includes functionality to process large data sets (~TB) and generate intermediate data products (~10s GB) which our group uses for analysis.  I want to integrate travis-ci tests to this package, but obviously downloading all of that data is impossible; there also isn't any API for the travis servers to poke at it.  It is possible to have the travis tests run on ***our*** server instead of on travis; but to still update the status online and synch with github (i.e. the little travis badge/icon)?

Answer (score 1):

Would it suit your purposes to just test a small subset of your data? If that was the case you could just upload some extracts to Travis for testing?

If you want to test with all your data, you might be able to use [Travis Enterprise](https://enterprise.travis-ci.com/) for this, as it runs on your own infrastructure.

The build images that Travis Enterprise uses [can be customised](https://enterprise.travis-ci.com/docs#customizing-build-images), so they could be configured to mount your data to perform testing.